# How to make cheesecake less tangy

Tags: baking, cheesecake

I love cheesecake, however I despise the acidic, tangy taste associate with cream cheese and yogurt. I recently purchased some that didn't have that taste at all, just smooth an delicious. 
I'd like to know how to make cheesecake without the tang it generally has.

Comment: They might've made it was mascarpone or ricotta.  (the texture of ricotta cheesecake can be noticable, though)

Comment: Google 'Italian Cheesecake'.

Comment: Did you purchase the cheesecake you liked at a bakery or at a store?  If you bought the cheesecake at a store, what are the primary ingredients listed on the package - knowing some of the ingredients might help the users here point you in a good direction.  If you purchased it at a bakery (or restaurant), ask someone there what type of cheesecake it was.  Also, was the cheesecake dense or was it kind of fluffy?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, if I use a cheese like Philadelphia, it will have a more cheesy tang, whereas using Mascarpone has a smoother creamier taste.  I also find that using higher fat creams will give a more creamy taste, as opposed to a lighter cream and particularly sour cream, which will add to the tang.  I've actually just made a very creamy tasting cheesecake today using Mascarpone and extra thick double (heavy) cream.  For my palette, it is too creamy and doesn't taste enough like cheesecake, but it may suit you.

Answer (score 3):

In its most basic form the answer is- Less cheese or more sugar...

I'm not sure if you are talking about baked or geletin style cheesecake.

In a baked cheesecake its the eggs that makes it set. In a geletin cheesecake its the geletin making it set. Either way substituting part of the sour/ acidic ingredients for cream will have no/little effect on the integrity of the final product, except maybe the texture will be smoother.

In fact there is nothing to say you can't take all the cheese out of the recipe and replace it with cream other than the fact it will no longer be a cheesecake and more of a panacota (geletin) or creme-brulee (baked)...

Comment: I don't know if "more sugar" would be a good answer. It reduces the perception of the cheesecake being sour. But yogurt has its own lactic acid flavor which is more than just being sour, and cream cheese has a taste which is even less based on pure perception of sourness. I think the OP wants their cake to taste blander, not just to be less sour.

Comment: I thought that too which is why I talked more about the cheese aspect rather than simply adding more sweetness. Apart from anything else sugar doesn't effect the ph of acid all it does is mask it, if you really want to neutralize the acidic properties you need to add an alkaline such as http://msk-ingredients.com/MolecularGastronomy/TricksoftheTrade/calcium-hydroxide/CalciumHydroxide-3909

Answer (score 0):

Some recipes for cheesecake have sour cream in them, some don't. This [Martha Stewart recipe](http://www.marthastewart.com/313705/classic-cheesecake) doesn't, I've made it, and it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

From experience:

**Make sure your cream cheese is at room temperature. Beat it well. Then add the sugar, and beat well again. The mixture should be smooth and silky, with no lumps. Proceed with the rest of the recipe.**

The first few times I made cheesecake, it always left a sour aftertaste. I discovered that I wasn’t beating the cream cheese and sugar enough. A lot of recipes stress the importance of not beating too much air into the cheesecake, but this really only becomes a problem once you add cream and/or eggs. I haven't made a sour cheesecake since.